# Sort object of objects by property value (passing by tuples)

Tags: javascript

I've this object:

```js
const data = {
  FR: {total: 875, min: 4, cutValue: 56},
  DE: {total: 478, min: 50, cutValue: 5},
  UK: {total: 1505, min: 0, cutValue: 0},
  PO: {total: 2995, min: 0, cutValue: 4},
  IT: {total: 1840, min: 10, cutValue: 3},
  ES: {total: 629, min: 30, cutValue: 33},
}
```

and I want to transform it to an array of tuples sorted by `total` value.
So the result should be:

```js
[
  ['PO', {total: 2995, min: 0, cutValue: 4}],
  ['IT', {total: 1840, min: 10, cutValue: 3}],
  ['UK', {total: 1505, min: 0, cutValue: 0}],
  ['FR', {total: 875, min: 4, cutValue: 56}],
  ['ES', {total: 629, min: 30, cutValue: 33}],
  ['DE', {total: 478, min: 50, cutValue: 5}],
]
```

because `PO` has the highest `total` value.

So I can use [`toPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#toPairs) from Lodash to create the tuples array but then how can I sort them by `total` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla JS use `Object.entries`:

```js
const data = {FR: {total: 875, min: 4, cutValue: 56},DE: {total: 478, min: 50, cutValue: 5},UK: {total: 1505, min: 0, cutValue: 0},PO: {total: 2995, min: 0, cutValue: 4},IT: {total: 1840, min: 10, cutValue: 3},ES: {total: 629, min: 30, cutValue: 33},};

let result = Object.entries(data).sort((a, b) => b[1].total - a[1].total);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.sortBy`:

```js
const data = {
  FR: {total: 875, min: 4, cutValue: 56},
  DE: {total: 478, min: 50, cutValue: 5},
  UK: {total: 1505, min: 0, cutValue: 0},
  PO: {total: 2995, min: 0, cutValue: 4},
  IT: {total: 1840, min: 10, cutValue: 3},
  ES: {total: 629, min: 30, cutValue: 33},
};

const sorted = _.sortBy(_.toPairs(data), ([, { total }]) => -total);

console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the exact transformation applied by `Object.entries`:

```js
const data = {
  FR: {total: 875, min: 4, cutValue: 56},
  DE: {total: 478, min: 50, cutValue: 5},
  UK: {total: 1505, min: 0, cutValue: 0},
  PO: {total: 2995, min: 0, cutValue: 4},
  IT: {total: 1840, min: 10, cutValue: 3},
  ES: {total: 629, min: 30, cutValue: 33},
};

console.log(Object.entries(data).sort((v1, v2) => v2[1].total - v1[1].total));
```

Note that `v1` and `v2` each look something like:

```
[ 'UK', {total: 1505, min: 0, cutValue: 0} ]
```

The sort function needs to access the `total` property; this means getting the second item in the array (index 1), and then getting this second item's `total` property.

If you like fancy destructuring assignments you can also use:

```
Object.entries(data).sort((v1, v2) => {
  let [ , { total: total1 } ] = v1;
  let [ , { total: total2 } ] = v2;
  return total2 - total1;
})
```